# Running a Matlab p-file coded for Windows on a MacOS

Tags: matlab, path, filepath

I have several Windows sourced p-files internally coded with the '\' file separator that I want to run on Matlab under macOS.

I get errors caused by the '\' because macOS uses '/'.

eg The pfile tries to call a file named "model\xyz' which causes a warning:

```
     "Name is nonexistent or not a directory: model\  "
```

1) Is there code that I might insert somewhere to recognise the 'model\' call from the pcode file and change it to 'model/'  before it is used by MATLAB addpath?

2) Is there a generic fix I could apply to the addpath code?

3) Or better still is there a way to modify the Windows p-file without access to its source code so that it will run under macOS?

Comment: Do you have access to the author of the p code? They should be using `fullfile` for all of their paths so you don't end up with this issue. You're pretty much out of luck otherwise.

Comment: p-code files are encrypted, their goal is to hide the source code and prevent your from making changes. So unless you can ask the author to fix the code, you're out of luck. This code was badly written, in MATLAB there is no need to write code that fails on a different platform.

Comment: @excaza Using `filesep` instead back/forward slashes is another OS-independent way to achieve this.

Comment: @Wolfie Cool. Why bother littering the line with `filesep` when you can just make one `fullfile` call?

Comment: @excaza its certainly not as flexible, I'd always use `fullfile`, but these things are useful to know! I can more easily imagine using `filesep` to *parse* a path with OS independence, rather than create one

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do (none of which are particularly easy; listed here in increasing order of how nasty I think they are):

1. Contact the author of the code and ask them to fix it.
2. Install an older MATLAB version (`R2007b <= ver < R2015b`, I think) which allowed debugging (stepping into) p-files **within MATLAB**, then, assuming that there is some line in the original source code that does

   ```
   filepath = ['model' '\' 'xyz.m'];
   ```

   step until you see `filepath` appear in the workspace (having the wrong path in it), then simply edit the value to the correct path, and hope for the best.
3. (Essentially the same idea as before, but on newer MATLAB versions, VERY DIFFICULT to pull off) 
    Obtain an **external** debugger, attach to the MATLAB process, run the p-file and scan the memory for the contents of `filepath`. When you discover it, change the value to the correct path and detach/disable the debugger.
4. If this code relies on some external (and open source) function to get (or use) the path, you can modify *its* behavior  to output the string you want. This requires some knowledge about the source code.
5. Find/make a tool for decoding p-files and fix the resulting source code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I describe how my problem was solved:

1. As suggested by Dev-iL I was eventually able to locate the author and he modified his code. This is the best solution but it took some time and is not always possible.
2. Based on: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/117110-dealing-with-and-windows-vs-unix-for-path-definition I located a module (I've forgotten its name) within the Matlab package which handles file calls and intercepted all incoming file path names containing the '\' Windows separator, and replaced them with the always acceptable '/'. This quick and dirty fix worked until solution 1. was obtained.

Thanks to all who responded so quickly to this question.

Comment: Here is some useful Matlab code. To detect Windows backslashes in filenames and replace them with Unix forward slashes in MATLAB, you can use the strrep function to replace all instances of backslashes with forward slashes. Here is an example code snippet:

    filename = 'C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\file.txt';
    unix_filename = strrep(filename, '\', '/');

This will replace all backslashes in filename with forward slashes, resulting in unix_filename being 'C:/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/file.txt'.